# recording from an old camera C#

Tags: c#, camera

there's a lot of easy ways to find connected cameras and record from them, though non of them work because the web cams used are a bit old, i tried using [Aforge](http://www.aforgenet.com) and [Ozeki Camera SDK](http://camera-sdk.com/p_6607-how-to-get-started-on-onvif-ip-camera-programming-in-c-.html) but they both didn't detect the cameras, the only way the camera was detected by using the following code:

first a class to save the detected cameras:

```
class USBDeviceInfo
{
    public USBDeviceInfo(string deviceID, string pnpDeviceID, string description, string name)
    {
        this.DeviceID = deviceID;
        this.PnpDeviceID = pnpDeviceID;
        this.Description = description;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public string DeviceID { get; private set; }
    public string PnpDeviceID { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public string name { get; private set; }
}
```

then detecting them with the following:

```
using System.Management;


List<USBDeviceInfo> devices = new List<USBDeviceInfo>();
ManagementObjectCollection collection;
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE (PNPClass = 'Image' OR PNPClass = 'Camera')"))
collection = searcher.Get(); // gets all connected cameras devices
foreach (var device in collection)
            {
                devices.Add(new USBDeviceInfo(
                (string)device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID"),
                (string)device.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID"),
                (string)device.GetPropertyValue("Description"),
                (string)device.GetPropertyValue("Name")
                ));
            }
```

now the camera was detected, how can i start recording from it now?

*Please note that the drivers are installed and the cameras are working fine*

Comment: Not all USB devices are the same.  Using a generic Microsoft Driver doesn't usually work.  Go to vendor webpage and look for a compatible driver.

Comment: the camera actually works and the driver is installed, the problem is that it's not detected with more simple ways

Comment: Is it a com device, or a file system?  Cameras usually have a smart drive when pictures are stored so they are not the same as other USB devices.

Comment: i don't know exactly, but they are USB web cameras plugged in an ATM machine

Comment: Look at Device Manager.  A Serial port USB will show up in the serial ports.